# Запись и чтение данных в SQLite3 на с++

Tags: c++, sqlite3

Добрый день! Как правильно записать данные в sqlite, и соответственно считать их на с++? 
Данные представляют собой несколько переменных разных типов, числа, символы, всего 10 элементов. 
Запись производится каждые 10 секунд, примерно по 40 строк (отсюда возникает еще один вопрос, как оптимальнее загружать данные).

На хабре нашел интересную   [статью](https://habrahabr.ru/post/149356/), где автор подробно объясняет об особенностях sqlite. Там же, он прилагает код работы с этой бд:`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sqlite3.h"
const char* SQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo(a,b,c); INSERT INTO FOO 
VALUES(1,2,3); INSERT INTO FOO SELECT * FROM FOO;";

int main(int argc, char **argv){

sqlite3 *db = 0; // хэндл объекта соединение к БД
char *err = 0;

// открываем соединение
if( sqlite3_open("my_cosy_database.dblite", &db) )
fprintf(stderr, "Ошибка открытия/создания БД: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
// выполняем SQL
else if (sqlite3_exec(db, SQL, 0, 0, &err))
{
fprintf(stderr, "Ошибка SQL: %sn", err);
sqlite3_free(err);
}
// закрываем соединение
sqlite3_close(db);
return 0;
}`
```

Код работает, БД создается, все отлично. Вопрос в том, как мне формировать sql запрос автоматически, т.е. получается, что `char* SQL` является константным значением, и например если я захочу добавить к запросу SQL переменную, которая будет постоянно обновляться, то будет возникать соответствующая ошибка, пример:

`char* for_ins= "foooo";
 char* SQL_check = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo(a,b,c); INSERT INTO foo" + for_ins;`
ошибка:

> char  *foo_ins выражение должно относиться к целочисленному типу или типу перечисления без области видимости

Соответственно, не ясно вообще как читать данные из этой же таблицы в переменную.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ошибка в коде.**

> char* for_ins= "foooo";
>   char* SQL_check = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo(a,b,c); INSERT INTO foo" + for_ins;

Стандартный компилятор MS VS 2013 в данном случае выдаёт ошибку:

```
Error   1   error C2110: '+' : cannot add two pointers
```

Что собственно логично.

Если нет ограничений на использование библиотеки std, рекомендую для данных целей воспользоваться **std:string** и **std::string::c_str()** для получения const char*:

```
 std::string for_ins = "foooo";
 std::string SQL_check = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo(a,b,c); INSERT INTO foo" + for_ins;
 puts(SQL_check.c_str());
```

**Пример использования SQLite**

```
bool foo(const string &date, const string &product_id, const string &material_id, const string &order_id){
    string statistic_query = string("INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(date, ProductId, MaterialId, orderId)") +
    "VALUES (\"" + date + "\", \"" + product_id + "\", \"" + material_id + "\", \"" + order_id + "\");";

    request_status = sqlite3_exec(statistic_db, statistic_query.c_str(), Callback, 0, &m_error_mesage);

    if (request_status != SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        //Something went wrong
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Оптимальность**

Оптимальность - понятие относительное. Если считаешь, что приложение будет работать штатно (не будет скачков напряжения и перезагрузок, никто не будет убивать процесс), то я бы формировал временные очереди на 40 сообщений, используя **BEGIN TRANSACTION** и потом бы уже пачку коммитил. Пример из обучающего урока ([SQLite transaction tutorial](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-transaction/)):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO account_changes(account_no,flag,amount,changed_at) values(100,'-',1000,datetime('now'));

INSERT INTO account_changes(account_no,flag,amount,changed_at) values(200,'+',1000,datetime('now'));

COMMIT;
```